# Getting value in a nested dictionary Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get all the values in a nested dictionary with the same key. `"topic"` is of interest in this case.

```json
{
    "0": {"title": "ctitle", "entry": {"topic": "Hello", "entry": "Walaalka"}},
    "1": {"title": "ctitle", "entry": {"topic": "Walaalka", "entry": "Hello"}},
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your dictionary is invalid as you are using the key `"0"` twice in the same hierarchy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys shouldn't be duplicated. Your dictionary should look like below:

```
d = {"0": {"title": "ctitle", "entry": {"topic": "Hello", "entry": "Walaalka"}}, "1": {"title": "ctitle", "entry": {"topic": "Walaalka", "entry": "Hello"}}}
```

In order to access "topic" you can just go follow keys:

```
>>> d["0"]["entry"]["topic"]
```

And the output will be:

```
'Hello'
```

Edit: In order to get all topics you can use just simple list comprehension:

```
topics =  [d[i]["entry"]["topic"] for i in d]
```

List will look like:
['Hello', 'Walaalka']

Comment: The question was: "How do I get **all** topics"